# Has application US 13/346,940 been granted?

Tags: pre-grant, pro-se, legal-status, us20130174818

What is the current status of the patent application number [US 13/346,940](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130174818)?

Answer (score 4):

This patent received a final rejection on January 24, 2014 and was listed as abandoned on August 6, 2014.

The examiner cited:

> Claim 1 is rejected under 35 U.S.C. 103(a) as being unpatentable over Marley [US Pat. No. 2,586,547](http://www.google.com/patents/US2586547) in view of Cosmopulos [US Pat. No. 4,157,828](http://www.google.com/patents/US4157828).

Additionally:

> Claim 1 is rejected under 35 U.S.C. 112(a) or 35 U.S.C. 112 (pre-AIA),
>   first paragraph, as failing to comply with the written description
>   requirement.

This is a good example of what can happen when a patent application is filed *pro se* without a proper understanding of the patent code.